# Does older xamp server does not allow json or create any issue

Tags: apache2, php, amazon-ec2, xampp, json

I am running my pages on localhost with latest xamp, which fetch data from table and create json string. Which used for google chart creation.
On localhost it work nice.

Same code, database I put on linux ec2 instance. Which takes wrong json string and does not give result.

Does is it due to xamp version difference?

Localhost has `PHP 5.4.16` and ec2 server `PHP 5.3.8`.

code is:

```
<?php
$mysqli =mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM view_name');

  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'pcount', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'ncount', 'type' => 'number')
);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {
      $temp = array();
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['ind_type']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Index_val']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
//$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

on localhost it gives json string

```
{"cols":[{"label":"pcount","type":"string"},{"label":"ncount","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"pcount"},{"v":179}]},{"c":[{"v":"ncount"},{"v":237}]}]}
```

json string while I run on ec2 instance:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"pcount","type":"string"},{"label":"ncount","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}
```

Tables is:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ind_type | Index_val |
+----------+-----------+
| pcount   |       179 |
| ncount   |       237 |          which is same on localhost and ec2 instance.
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: maybe you should do a `print_r($result);` and post it here to see if your result is really what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

i can be wrong because I use pdo instead of mysqli but shouldn't you do a `$result->fetch_assoc()` to get an associative array like explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php ?

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

By the way i think you mixed Object oriented style and Procedural style. Please see Example1 and Example2 on php.net.